# Elasticsearch Java API: query string validation

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch Java API (version 2.1.1) with a *Query String Query*. The query string is entered by the user and may contain syntax errors. Right now it seems like the query is sent to the server, the response is a *shardFailure* and an exception is thrown.

Is there an easy way to validate the query in the API before sending it to the server? Right now I'm catching the exception, but it does not feel right to bother the server with these queries.

Query is built like this:

```
QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("error)");
```

Example response:

> QueryParsingException[Failed to parse query [error)]]; nested:
>   NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Cannot parse 'error)': Encountered "
>   ")" ") "" at line 1, column 5.

edit:
To be clear:
It is totally ok for the query to contain special characters like brackets or quotes. I just want to check if the user entered a correct search query (e.g. all brackets/quotes in pairs).

Answer (score 0):

This is too late, but Elasticsearch now has a [Validate API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html) which just validates but doesn't makes a server call.

The equivalent [Java Client API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-indices-validate-query.html)

Answer (score -2):

You will have to parse your string and escape all special characters before passing the string to your method.

```
QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(escapeSpecialCharacters("error)"));

String escapeSpecialCharacters(String str) {

   str.replaceAll(/[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]/, "\\'");
}
```

You can also remove all special characters if you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not what I want. Special characters like brackets are allowed, but they have to be in pairs to be syntactically correct.

Comment: If you have two opening brackets, then you also need two closing ones, otherwise it's a syntax error.

Comment: I guess there is no way of applying validation at ES level, but yes you can validate a string before passing it to `QueryBuilders`